# What is the best and most secure way to forward http to https or port 80 to 443 Apache?

Tags: apache, redirect, https, port, ports

So I am looking for the best way to setup my https ssl website. I will show you my current configuration.

000-default.conf - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC3qD.png

ports.conf - https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7uMH.png

I want it so if someone types website.com or www.website.com it goes to https ://www.website.com

I already have it setup so it does this. But is this secure and the most effective way of doing it? Do I even need port 80 at all and have people not need to type https manually?

I hope I explained my situation well enough. Any help and advise would be appreciated!

Comment: You should include text rather than linking to screenshots of a terminal running an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simple Redirect in a port 80 virtualhost to the port 443 vhost is perfectly normal/fine.  It's secure and effective and not something to dwell on.